# How can I add an admob banner inside a specify java file?

Tags: admob

Everyone, it is admob banner code :

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

where can I put the above  code into following code and works? thx

jave code something following:

http://pastebin.com/kB9tUCA5

Answer (score 0):

You should see the basic courses for Android

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            restore = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("restore");
            loading = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("loading");
            preload = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("preload");

        } else {

            App.getInstance().setCurrentChatId(chatId);

            restore = false;
            loading = false;
            preload = false;
        }

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```